# Do I need a multilevel page table in the following design?

Tags: virtual-memory, paging

I am practicing paging in virtual memory and came across a question with the following details

- 44-bit address space
- 16KB page size
- 16 Bytes Page table entry (PTE)

If I understand paging correctly then there would be 2^30 pages, and the page table size if 2^44 bytes

My questions is, do I use a single-level page table or do I have to go with multi-level and why?

Comment: Please add to your question: How did you determine total page table size? What would force you to use multilevel page tables?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yeah, you probably do. The total size of the page table is $2^{30}\cdot2^4=2^{34} = 16GB$. Clearly prohibitively large. A better arrangement would be a three-level page table, where each level maps ten bits of the virtual address. Since each entry is 16 bytes, the size of a page table for one level is $2^4\cdot2^{10} = 16KB$ which neatly fits into one 16KB page.

Comment: 16GB is a decent chunk of memory, but is it really *prohibitively* large? To me it looks more like an odd choice, but possible.

Comment: Also multiply the figure by the number of processes running on the system.

Comment: Still possible, just weird